# Javascript Getter/Setter in Angular Service with 2 Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am messing with javascript getters and setters in my service layer. I am using 2 controllers. The first controller just displays some text. The second controller allows hiding it. I am trying to figure out why one method works while another does not.

Here is the working example:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('data', function () {
  var fac = [];
  var state = false;

  fac.hideIt = function (hide) {
    state = hide;
  };

  fac.hidden = function() {
    return state;
  }

  return fac;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.hide = data.hidden;
});

app.controller('SecCtrl', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.hideAbove = function () {
    var hide = true;
    data.hideIt(hide);
  };
});
```

Here is the not working example:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('data', function () {
  var fac = [];

  fac.hide = {
                state: false, 
                get get() {
                  return this.state
                }, 
                set set(hide) {
                  return this.state = hide;
                }
              };

  return fac;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.hide = data.hide.get;
});

app.controller('SecCtrl', function($scope, data) {

  $scope.hideAbove = function () {
    var hide = true;
    data.hide.set = hide;
    console.log(data.hide.get)
  }
});
```

HTML (shared by both)

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-hide="hide()">
        <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecCtrl">
      <div ng-click="hideAbove()">CLICK HERE </div>
    </div>  

  </body>
```

So my question is why does using the getter and setters in the non-working block of code not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in your html:

```
ng-hide="hide()"
```

The problem is simple you need to change `hide` property into method inside `MainCtrl`

```
$scope.hide = function() {
    return data.hide.get;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rahilwazir/sk3e9e90/1/)

> But you will say why the first example worked?

Because in the first example `data.hidden` does return function literal while the latter example just returns the value from getter.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a service rather than a factory for this. A factory's value is set to the return value of the function you pass to it. There is not really a concept of "this" in a factory ("this" probably points to the window object). "this" in a service points to the service instance.

```
app.service('data', function () {
  this.state = false;

  this.hide = {
      get value() {
          return this.state;
      },
      set value(hide) {
          this.state = hide;
      }
  };
});
```

Comment: I should note that you could still do this with the factory approach, but just put the `state` outside of the `fac.hide` object and remove the `this` in front of the `state` in the get and set methods. Also where you declare `fac` you should set it to an object literal not an array ie `fac = {};` rather than `fac = [];`

Comment: I have it working with the factory in the working example. I just don't understand why it doesn't work in the other example.

Comment: It is because you have declared `state` within the `hide` object. Put `var state = false;` under where you have put `var fac = [];` and then change `this.state` to just `state` in the get and set methods. `this` will not reference an object literal in javascript, only an instance of a function created with the `new` keyword. If it still doesn't make sense, ill make a fiddle and link it to show you.

Comment: @BenGuest I don't agree, `this` does reference to object literal.

Comment: yeah i thought this does reference an object literal